# How to use Jmeter OS Process sampler process python script

Tags: python, mysql, jmeter

I am trying to use the jmeter OS sampler process python script to insert a row in a MySQL database. Python seems to work but jmeter did not call it successfully.

I have tried the following:

```
Command python
parameter /root/buildResult/tests/bssTest/insert.py
parameter ${V_URL}
parameter ${V_DBName}
parameter ${V_UserName}
parameter ${V_Password}
```

Unfortunately, this did not work.

Comment: Can you share more details? Env is windows or linux? Why use python? or OS sampler? You can run a query using JDBC sampler. If OS sampler is to be involved that you can use OS sampler to call CMD and from there you can perform required actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may have to use full path to python interpreter like `/usr/bin/python`
2. If JMeter Variables contain spaces you may need to surround them with quotation marks. Same for the situation with characters which require escaping

   [image: OS Process Sampler]

If it doesn't work still add [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and inspect request and response details.

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more detailed explanation.